# Phonegap app to native app update does not carry forward the sqlite database files in iOS 7 devices(only)

Tags: ipad, sqlite, cordova, ios5, ios7

We have published an app(iPad only) developed using phonegap(v2.6.0) in the app store. We are currently developing an update to the app which is written entirely in the native iOS API(XCode 4.6.1).
Phonegap used to store the sqlite database file here:

**`"<APP-HOME>/Library/Webkit/LocalStorage/file__0/"`**

For the native app, we are using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains and NSLibraryDirectory to get the Library folder.
After updating the app to the native version in an iPad(iOS 5.1), the file seems to be moved to here:

**`"<APP-HOME>/Library/Caches/file__0/"`**

And we restore the db to the new version of the app by copying the contents from old sqlite db file it exists in any of the above paths to a new sqlite db file inside the Library folder.
In iOS 5.1 iPad and iOS 6.1 iPad simulator, this update seems to be working correctly.

But for an iOS 7 iPad, after the app update these folders are missing. It only contains two folders:

```
"<APP-HOME>/Library/Caches"
"<APP-HOME>/Library/Caches/Snapshots"
```

So we are not able to restore the old app user settings to the new native app. If anybody have an idea whats going on or have a fix for this please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. But if someone has issue better check the path again.
This turned out be an issue with case sensitivity issue with iOS simulators.

The path I used contained the string **'Webkit'**, which should be actually **'WebKit'**.
iOS simulators does not have problem with the case sensitivity and works correctly while in the device it fails.